# Why resource folder keeping removed files .Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, resources

I removed files from Resource by"Remove resource" menu but I find the old files in Resource folder in my project!
and when removing files manually from the folder in the project folder, I have resource error file.
Why resource remover cant delete unused files from resource folder?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Its really important to ask questions properly here. Have a look at [ask] and [mcve]. Specifically You need to include relevant code - ideally code that we can run ourselves and find the problem. Thanks

Comment: Hi. sorry, this isn't an error code. it is a way for remove resource file by the visual studio menu.